# Firestore - Best way to retrieve historical records at an interval?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I’m using the cloud firestore (with the flame priced plan), and every minute I’m storing the price of a stock. Here is what a document looks like:

`{ ingestTimeEpoch: 1511468780797, price:20, stockName:foo }`

I want to be able to be able to get the last 30 prices on a 15 min interval, such as the price from 1 minute ago, 16 min ago, 31 min ago etc... I could just get all records in the collection, and get the 0th price in the array, 14th price, 29th price etc... but something like that would make me use 30 prices * 15 min interval = 450 reads a minute, which is 648,000 reads a day- way over my flame plan quota (250k reads / day).

And I don’t think I could store these records once every 15 min (instead of every 1 min), as I do need them once a minute for other queries. Also, I’m tracking more than 1 stock so need to try and get these values for all of them - once a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any query capabilities that allow you to say "give me every 15th record".

Instead of looking for that silver bullet, I'd add some duplicate data that makes you query simple. If you want one price for every 15 minutes, create an additional collection that contains just one document for every 15 minutes. Then in that collection your query is trivial: just retrieve however many documents/quarters you need.